# TFS Build: stuck when running .exe

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I run BUILD in TFS, and one of the steps contains executing the .exe file.

If i run this .exe file separately, on the remote PC where BUILD is running, it operates correctly and successfully.

But when it is being called from BUILD, it simply gets stuck on this stage.

I used debug mode, copied exactly the command it is running of this type:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Agents\Agent2.....<my path>...\my_file.exe"
```

Copied it, used the Win+R (run), pasted - it works perfectly.

When can't the BUILD run the .exe file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because the application is trying to do something UI-y. The agent is running as a service and any application running during the build should not use the UI in any way. Anything that relies on Windows Forms, WPF or the Message Pump won't work as long as the agent isn't running Interactively.

Try running the exact command from a scheduled task, that should also allow you to test non-interactively.

Comment: or the .exe is trying to use something you have in your user profile but is it not in the profile of the account running TFS Build

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have tried what you have suggested.

1. no UI is being opened. All the program runs in shell mode
2. I have tried using the Task Scheduler and it worked perfect